# How to rename file tabs in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

When working with an MVC framework, my controllers and models have similar names which can sometimes cause confusion when I have a controller and model files open and they are similarly named.

I looked through many settings and couldn't find any option to rename the tabs or group them together. There used to be a package for it however it was for Sublime Text 2.

I understand that I can simply rename the files themselves but I want them to be as closely named to the controller as possible.

Also in case anyone asks, I am using a self-made framework that we use for in-house internal systems.

Is there a way to accomplish this, or a method to better organise the file tabs so I can have all my models, controller, view and other files in some sort of tab-group? Or perhaps there is a view/layout that would address this issue?

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" are highly recommend pages to read. It's really important to show the effort you put into solving your problem. Without that we have to make assumptions about your knowledge or where you searched or what you tried, which wastes all our time. Also, "[ask]" is important. Grammar is important on SO; The site isn't a message board or a forum, it's more like a reference book.

Answer (score 1):

I found the old [RenameTab](https://github.com/frozenice/RenameTab/) plugin for Sublime Text 2 and made a few little changes.

Create `RenameTab.py` and save it in the `Packages/User` folder:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class RenameTabCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    self.view.window().show_input_panel("Tab Name:", self.view.name(), self.on_done, None, None)

  def on_done(self, input):
    self.view.set_name(input)
```

Create `Tab Context.sublime-menu` and save it in the `Packages/User` folder:

```
[
  { "command": "rename_tab", "caption": "Rename Tab" }
]
```

Add this to the Sublime Keybindings settings (re-map it to whatever key you want):

```
 { "keys": ["alt+w"], "command": "rename_tab", "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
  }
```

Right-click on the file tab at the top and press "Rename Tab" in the context menu and it will prompt you to create a new name. This won't change the filename, just the name of the tab for easy viewing/reading/organising.

[RenameTab](https://github.com/frozenice/RenameTab/) was written by frozenice, however he hasn't changed it since 2012, or tested it for Sublime Text 3. I changed the layout of the `import sublime` and `import sublime_plugin`. (I'm not even sure if that made a difference.)

Comment: If `view.set_name` is set, it will cause the buffer to be disconnected from the disk file, and `view.file_name()` returns empty.